# Why is this output blank?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I know I must be doing something simple wrong.  When I do this:

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($event->when);
 echo '</pre>';
```

I get this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Zend_Gdata_Extension_When Object
    (
        [_rootElement:protected] => when
        [_reminders:protected] => 
        [_startTime:protected] => 2011-06-16T10:00:00.000-05:00
        [_valueString:protected] => 
        [_endTime:protected] => 2011-06-17T11:00:00.000-05:00
        [_rootNamespace:protected] => gd
        [_rootNamespaceURI:protected] => 
        [_extensionElements:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_text:protected] => 
        [_namespaces:protected] => Array
            (
                [atom] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                            )

                    )

                [app] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://purl.org/atom/app#
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://www.w3.org/2007/app
                            )

                    )

                [gd] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005
                            )

                    )

                [openSearch] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/
                            )

                    )

                [rss] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I'm then trying to get `startTime` by doing this:

```
$StartTime = $event->when->startTime;
```

But I'm not getting anything.

And yet, when I do this:

```
 pr($event->published);
```

I get this:

```
Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Published Object
(
[_rootElement:protected] => published
[_rootNamespace:protected] => atom
[_rootNamespaceURI:protected] => 
[_extensionElements:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_text:protected] => 2011-06-15T03:32:14.000Z
[_namespaces:protected] => Array
    (
        [atom] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                    )

            )

        [app] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => http://purl.org/atom/app#
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => http://www.w3.org/2007/app
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

and I can do this:

```
$dateAdded = $event->published->text;
echo $dateAdded;
```

and I see an output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [to the official Zend_Gdata_Extension_When documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Gdata/Gdata/Zend_Gdata_Extension_When.html), there's a method called `getStartTime()` which will give you the time.

If you do `$event->when[0]->getStartTime()` or `$event->when[0]->startTime`, you'll get the start time.

Comment: Yeah- I tried that about 6 hours ago... Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry::getStartTime()

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getStartTime() on a non-object

Comment: Updated again... I read some more and look at the code you posted above and when is an array which explain why my previous example wan't working. Try `$event->when[0]->getStartTime()` or maybe even `$event->when[0]->startTime`.

Comment: man-that finally worked!  Thank you both for figuring this out.  I've been going cross-eyed on this!

Answer (score 1):

`startTime` is marked protected. You can't reference it from outside like you did. There must be a getter function 'getStartTime()' function in that object that would allow you to reference it publicly.

EDIT: Also it is returning an object array - not an single object, so you would need to reference the it like: `$event[0]->getterFunction()` or loop through the array with a `foreach` accessing the individual objects in the loop

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case.  For example, I can access   pr($event->published); and even though the array says [_rootElement:protected] => published, I can still do   $dateAdded = $event->published->text;
and then echo $dateAdded and see the result.

Comment: Delving further into the class docs for this, I found that there is a magic _get method inherited from Zend_Gdata_App_Base (http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Gdata/App/Zend_Gdata_App_Base.html#__get). According to that, referencing the protected variable should magically call the getter method. Try `echo $event[0]->startTime` (you should reference the array element since it looks like your returned a array of event objects). It should work I think.